# Use a selection from a dropdown autofill other fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason, the `escrow_wire` and `escrow_note` fields won't populate with the values defined in my jQuery statement.

```js
if ($('#escrow_type').val() == "NO_PAYMENT") {
  $('#escrow_wire').val("0");
  $('#escrow_note').val("This escrow has been created WITHOUT sending a payment email to the client.");
  alert('Do you want to create this escrow WITHOUT sending an escrow payment email to the client?');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-xs-push-1 col-sm-push-1 col-md-push-3 col-lg-push-3">
  <div class="st-select st-select-full highlight">
    <select name="escrow_type" id="escrow_type" class="custom-select">
      <option value="">- select -</option>
      <option value="NO_PAYMENT">No Payment Required at this time</option>
      <option value="WIRE">Bank Wire</option>
      <!--option value="DEPOSIT">Bank Deposit</option-->
      <option value="CHECK">Cashier Check</option>
      <option value="MONEY_ORDER">Money Order</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-row form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 label-wrapper">Wire Amount</div>
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-xs-push-1 col-sm-push-1 col-md-push-3 col-lg-push-3">
      <input class="second-section-input form-control highlight" type="text" value="" name="escrow_wire" id="escrow_wire" placeholder="Escrow Amount"/>
     </div>
    </div>
  <div class="form-row form-group">
    <textarea id="escrow_note" class="rounded-area form-control highlight" rows="7" name="escrow_note" placeholder="Ex. one month deposit, contract to lease executed, etc.."></textarea>
      <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary ui-button btn-save shorter0" id="new_escrow" style="margin:8px 0 0 0;font-size:14px;">Save</button>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Are you expecting the condition to run once on load, or every time an option is selected? If the latter, you need to add a `change` event handler to the logic

Comment: I don't see `#escrow_wire` and `#escrow_note` in your code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I simply want the other two fields to fill with those values when NO_PAYMENT is selected. As it stands they do that, but only after the call to action is in progress. I want them to populate before it gets to that point.

I tried using a change event, but to no avail.

Comment: Have you try this way? https://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

To make this work you need to hook a `change` event handler to the `select` which executes your `if` condition to update the other fields as necessary:

```js
$('#escrow_type').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() === "NO_PAYMENT") {
    $('#escrow_wire').val("0");
    $('#escrow_note').val("This escrow has been created WITHOUT sending a payment email to the client.");
    alert('Do you want to create this escrow WITHOUT sending an escrow payment email to the client?');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-xs-push-1 col-sm-push-1 col-md-push-3 col-lg-push-3">
  <div class="st-select st-select-full highlight">
    <select name="escrow_type" id="escrow_type" class="custom-select">
      <option value="">- select -</option>
      <option value="NO_PAYMENT">No Payment Required at this time</option>
      <option value="WIRE">Bank Wire</option>
      <!--option value="DEPOSIT">Bank Deposit</option-->
      <option value="CHECK">Cashier Check</option>
      <option value="MONEY_ORDER">Money Order</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="text" id="escrow_wire" />
<input type="text" id="escrow_note" />
```

Note that you may also need to include an `else` statement which removes the values, depending on how and what data is sent to the server.

Comment: I see that I wrote my onChange wrong when I tried it earlier. Good on youRory